# How to plot an implicit surface in Octave?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I could plot the implicit surface (x^8)*(y^2)*(z^6) = 0 on MATLAB using the fimplicit3 command, but I couldn't find an analogous command in Octave.

Under the impression that MATLAB and Octave are compatible, I copy-pasted the same lines into Octave, and it returned an error message:
"error: 'fimplicit3' undefined near line 1 column 1".

How can I plot that on Octave?

Comment: If MATLAB and Octave were 100% compatible, why woudl anyone pay for MATLAB? :P

Comment: `fimplicit3` was introduced in MATALB R2016b. Octave (stll) doesn't have that function. New MATLAB functions usually take some time to appear in Octave, if they do

Comment: and they appear only if someone implements them... Patches are always welcome.

Comment: You could look at how the task would have been accomplished prior to 2016b, if possible. That may be possible with Octave. it would also have tge side benefit of making your code compatible with older versions of matlab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an equivalent function, but if you're simply trying to visualise what an object defined by such an equation *looks* like in space, you can simply create a grid of points, and obtain the isosurface at 0. This should work well, even for low-res grids.

for example, using the same example shown in [matlab's fimplicit3 documentation page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fimplicit3.html), i.e. the equation: 

  <sub>[image]</sub>

, defined in the interval [-5, 5] for x, y, and z, we have:

```
[x, y, z] = ndgrid(-5:1:5, -5:1:5, -5:1:5);
F = x.^2 + y.^2 - z.^2;
isosurface(F, 0);
```

[image]

You can play around with the properties of the isosurface object, or wrap it in a `patch` object, introduce `isonormals`, plot curvature lines on top using `plot3`, etc etc. In fact I wouldn't be surprised if that's what `fimplicit3` is doing under the hood in matlab.

---

<sub>PS: I used matlab's example rather than yours because yours seems a bit trivial: it is trivially zero whenever any of the individual variables are zero. So it's basically the three zero planes intersecting. Not sure if that was intentional or you meant something else</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of `meshX` or `surfX` functions to plot surfaces

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Three_002dDimensional-Plots.html